# Go - import sql.a: not a package file

Tags: mysql, go

I am using go 1.3. When i try to do mysql connectivity in golang it's working fine in linux console. While trying to do the same using go-ide 1.0 it throws like

> "import
>   /home/gold/software/go-ide/bundled/go-sdk/pkg/linux_amd64/database/sql.a:
>   not a package file"

Any one please suggest me how to solve this error.

```
>go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/usr/local/go/bin:/home/gold/software/go-ide/bundled/go-sdk/bin"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have no clue about `go-ide` but it looks like that IDE comes with a bundled go installation that is somehow broken.

`database/sql` is a standard package, the compiled file should be at`$GOROOT/pkg/linux_amd64/database/sql.a`.

According to your error message, your IDE somehow sets `GOROOT` to 
`/home/gold/software/go-ide/bundled/go-sdk`.

So you either fix the go installation in  that path or tell the IDE about the real `GOROOT`.

Comment: yes, you are right. In my go-ide, SDK path points to "/home/gold/software/go-ide/bundled/go-sdk". I tried to change '/usr/local/go' but it throws "The selected directory is not a valid home for Go SDK" error message.

Comment: maybe the Go SDK is a special crafted version. I've never heard about that - must be Go-IDE specific. I personally would keep away from editors/IDEs that impose their own mechanisms instead of using the established standard way...

Answer (score 0):

```
GOPATH="/usr/local/go/bin:/home/gold/software/go-ide/bundled/go-sdk/bin"
```

Your `GOPATH` is not supposed to reference bin folders.
It should reference the parent folder, in which you have `bin/`, `src/` and `pkg/` sub-folders.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed my GOPATH to point it's parent folder. But still i am facing the same error (echo $GOPATH => /usr/local/go:/home/gold/software/go-ide/bundled/go-sdk)

Comment: @Bathakarai try `GOPATH="/home/gold/software/go-ide/bundled/go-sdk/`: no need to add `/usr/local/go`

Comment: @VonC It looks more like an GOROOT than GOPATH issue. See my answer below.

Comment: @met I thought about the GOROOT, but it looks ok, so I didn't mention it. Your answer is still valid through.